# React CSSTransition Issues

Tags: css, reactjs, state, transition

I am trying to display header one in the beginning and then when clicked on, fade in the second header. However they both are showing up in beginning. My understanding is that the **in** prop is what controls when the children of get rendered. But for some reason they are being rendered in beginning when showTwo is false. Any help would be much appreciated.

Component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { CSSTransition } from "react-transition-group";
import "./Intro.css";

function Intro() {
  const [showOne, setShowOne] = useState(true);
  const [showTwo, setShowTwo] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      {showOne && <h1 onClick={() => setShowTwo(true)}>One!</h1>}
      <CSSTransition
        in={showTwo}
        timeout={750}
        onEnter={() => setShowOne(false)}
        classNames="creation"
      >
        <h2>Two!</h2>
      </CSSTransition>
    </>
  );
}

export default Intro;
```

CSS

```
.creation-enter {
    opacity: 0;
}

.creation-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 700ms;
}

.creation-exit {
    opacity: 1;
}

.creation-exit-active {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 700ms;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I was missing the prop **unmountOnExit** and misunderstanding what the **in** prop is for.

If others stumble upon this with similar issues, **in** is used to determine when the *-enter, *-enter-active, ... are added as classes.